# Extractor object in scala: difference between apply() and defined functions

Tags: scala

I'm relatively new to Scala and going through some tutorials I bumped into this code in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map,
SynchronizedMap, HashMap}

object MapMaker{
  def makeMap: Map[String,String] = {
    new HashMap[String,String] with SynchronizedMap[String,String]{
      override def default(key:String) = "Why do you want to know?" 
    }                                                   
  }
}

val capital = MapMaker.makeMap

capital ++ List("US" -> "Washington",
  "Paris" -> "France", "Japan" -> "Tokyo")
```

I tried to create an "apply" function inside the object and get rid of the MapMaker.makeMap syntax. So instead the code would look like this

```
object MapMaker{
  def apply: Map[String,String] = {
    new HashMap[String,String] with SynchronizedMap[String,String]{
      override def default(key:String) = "Why do you want to know?" 
    }                                                  
  }
}

val capital = MapMaker
capital ++ List("US" -> "Washington",
 "Paris" -> "France", "Japan" -> "Tokyo")
```

But it doesn't work since it returns a different kind of value

```
scala> val capital = MapMaker
capital: MapMaker.type = MapMaker$@105cb38b
```

I'm just doing this for the sake of learning when and how to use the "apply function" that you use in extractor objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
val capital = MapMaker
```

You are not implicitly calling the `apply` method of object `MapMaker`; you are just letting the variable `capital` refer to the `MapMaker` object.

First, you have to define the `apply` method with an empty parameter list `()`:

```
object MapMaker {
  // Note: def apply() instead of def apply
  def apply(): Map[String,String] = {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then, you can do this:

```
val capital = MapMaker()
```

Note that `MapMaker()` is short syntax for `MapMaker.apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

When writing `MapMaker` directly, you are not calling the `apply` method, but instead referencing the `object` itself. You can achieve the call by adding empty parenthesis:

```
val capital = MapMaker()
```